# Keep preroll or disable twitch preroll ads?

Tags: twitch.tv

I recently became an affiliate on Twitch (hurray!). I didn't understand the `Preroll Ads` field. 
For the purpose of remuneration, what should be done? Check `Keep preroll ads on my channel` or `Disable preroll ads when I run ads?`. I haven't found enough documentation about it, so
I cannot understand what is more convenient to do.

Thanks in advance.
**EDIT**: [my twitch channel](https://twitch.tv/memmo_twitch) (to help in the answer based on any parameters of my channel, and / or for those who want to follow me, I mainly treat programming in jython)